# Can you create Kerberos principals where the hostname is flexible? (Docker)

Tags: authentication, docker, apache-storm, kerberos, spn

I'm specifically trying to do this with Apache Storm (1.0.2), but it's relevant to any service that is secured with Kerberos. I'm trying to run a secured Storm cluster in Docker. There are a number of out-of-the-box docker images out there for Storm, and they work great unsecured. I'm using https://github.com/Baqend/docker-storm. I also have Storm running securely on RHEL VM's.

However, my understanding is that Kerberos ties hostnames to principals, so if I'm making service foobar available to clients, I need to create a principal of `foobar/hostname@REALM`. Then a client service might connect to `hostname` with principal `foobar`, Kerberos will look up `foobar/hostname@REALM` in its database, find that it's there (because we created a principal with exactly that name), and everything will work.

In my case, it's described here: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/configure_kerberos_for_storm.html. The nimbus authenticates as `storm/<nimbus host>@REALM`, and the supervisors and outside clients authenticate as `storm/REALM`. Everything works.

But here in 2017, we have containers and hostnames are no longer static. So how would I Kerberize a service that runs in Docker Data Center (or Kubernetes, etc)? I have to attach an unknown hostname to the server authentication. I imagine I could create a principal for all possible hostnames and dynamically pick the right one at startup based on where the container lives, but that's kludgy.

Am I misunderstanding how Kerberos works? Is there a solution here that I don't see? I see multiple examples online of people running Storm in Docker, but I can't imagine that nobody's clusters are secure.

Comment: I would add the tags *SPN* and *authentication* to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Apache Storm or Docker, but based on previous workings with JBOSS in a cluster in which an inbound client could be connecting to any one of a possible number of different hosts, then you would simply assign a virtual name to the entire pool at the load balancer and kerberize the service according to the virtual name instead of individual host name at the host level.  So if you're making service *foobar* available to clients, you need to create a service principal (SPN) of *foobar/virtualhostname@REALM* in your Directory to kerberize the service with. You assign that SPN to a user account (not a computer account) to give it the flexibility to work with any Kerberized service which uses that SPN.  If you are using Active Directory, you must create a keytab with the SPN inside of it, and place the keytab on each host running the kerberized service instance *foobar/virtualhostname@REALM*.

Comment: It makes sense. I'll need to try it and set up the appropriate DNS so that virtualhostname can be resolved both ways and configure Storm such that it advertises the virtualhostname and not it's real one. I'm a little hazy on some of this and new to Kerberos, but this makes sense. Thanks.